# Java NullpointerException In Facebook audience native ads, Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, facebook-ads-api

I want to display native ads in predetermined position within  my RecyclerView, I have setup the code for showing the ads template but once I integrated the code for  showing Facebook Audience native ads the app clashes, I do not know what to after this, is there any one with a solution?

```
  @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                return new ViewHolderBoxOffice(layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_movie_box_office, parent, false));
            case 2:
                return new NativeAdViewHolder(layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_ads_facebook, parent, false));
        }
        /*View view=null;

       if(viewType==10){

            adView= (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_ads_facebook, nativeAdContainer,  false);
           nativeAdContainer.addView(adView);
        } else {
             view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_movie_box_office, parent, false);

        }
        ViewHolderBoxOffice viewHolder = new ViewHolderBoxOffice(view);

        return viewHolder;*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case 0:
                ViewHolderBoxOffice v_holder = (ViewHolderBoxOffice) holder;
                Movie currentMovie = mlistMovies.get(position);
                v_holder.movieTitle.setText(currentMovie.getTitle());
                Date movieReleaseDate = currentMovie.getReleaseDateTheater();
                if (movieReleaseDate != null) {
                    String formmattedDate = dateFormat.format(movieReleaseDate);
                    v_holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(formmattedDate);
                } else {
                    v_holder.movieReleaseDate.setText(Constants.NA);

                }
                int audienceScore = currentMovie.getAudienceScore();
                if (audienceScore == -1) {
                    v_holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(0.0F);
                    v_holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(0.5F);
                } else {
                    v_holder.movieAudienceScore.setRating(currentMovie.getAudienceScore() / 20.0F);
                    v_holder.movieAudienceScore.setAlpha(1.0F);
                }
                String urlThumbnail = currentMovie.getUrlThumbnail();
                loadImages(urlThumbnail, v_holder);
            case 2:
                NativeAdViewHolder mHolder=(NativeAdViewHolder)holder;
                // Setting the Text.

                nativeAd.unregisterView();
                mHolder.nativeAdCallToAction.setText(nativeAd.getAdCallToAction());
                mHolder.nativeAdSocialContext.setText(nativeAd.getAdSocialContext());
                mHolder.nativeAdTitle.setText(nativeAd.getAdTitle());
                mHolder.nativeAdBody.setText(nativeAd.getAdBody());

                // Downloading and setting the ad icon.
                NativeAd.Image adIcon = nativeAd.getAdIcon();
                NativeAd.downloadAndDisplayImage(adIcon, mHolder.nativeAdIcon);

                // Download and setting the cover image.
                NativeAd.Image adCoverImage = nativeAd.getAdCoverImage();
                mHolder.nativeAdMedia.setNativeAd(nativeAd);


                // Add adChoices icon
                if (adChoicesView == null)
                if(! (adView.getChildAt(0) instanceof AdChoicesView)){
                    adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(layoutInflater.getContext(), nativeAd, true);
                    adView.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
                }

                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(adView);
                default:
                    break;
        }
        if (position > previousPosition) {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

        } else {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

        }
        previousPosition = position;

    }

   /* @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {

        if (position == 10) {

        } else {

        }


        if (position > previousPosition) {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

        } else {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

        }
        previousPosition = position;


    }*/

    private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder) {
        if (urlThumbnail != null) {
            imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlistMovies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {

        View adView = NativeAdView.render(layoutInflater.getContext(), nativeAd, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = 0;
        if (position % 10 == 0) viewType = 2;
        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoaded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdError(AdError adError) {

    }
```

Here is the error

```
01-30 20:36:10.721 21295-21295/comeagain.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: comeagain.materialdesign, PID: 21295
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.onBindViewHolder(AdapterBoxOffice.java:165)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5217)
```

I am getting error in the line

```
 if(! (adView.getChildAt(0) instanceof AdChoicesView)){
```

Changed to this but still getting NullPointerException

```
   if(! (mHolder.adview.getChildAt(0) instanceof AdChoicesView)){
                   AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(layoutInflater.getContext(), nativeAd, true);
                    mHolder.adview.addView(adChoicesView, 0);
                }

                nativeAd.registerViewForInteraction(mHolder.adview);
                default:
                    break;
        }
        if (position > previousPosition) {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

        } else {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

        }
        previousPosition = position;

    }

   /* @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder, int position) {

        if (position == 10) {

        } else {

        }


        if (position > previousPosition) {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, true);

        } else {
            comeagain.materialdesign.anim.AnimationUtils.animate(holder, false);

        }
        previousPosition = position;


    }*/

    private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderBoxOffice holder) {
        if (urlThumbnail != null) {
            imageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    holder.movieThumbnail.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlistMovies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
        L.m("Ads is loaded, Jeez man that is good");
        System.out.println("Loaded in fragment");
        nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();

        nativeAd.setAdListener(this);



    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = 0;
        if (position % 10 == 0) viewType = 2;
        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoaded() {
        L.m("Ads is loaded, Jeez man that is good");
        System.out.println("Loaded in fragment");
        nativeAd = manager.nextNativeAd();

        nativeAd.setAdListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onAdError(AdError adError) {

    }

    class NativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView nativeAdIcon;
        private TextView nativeAdTitle;
        private TextView nativeAdBody;
        private MediaView nativeAdMedia;
        private TextView nativeAdSocialContext;
        private Button nativeAdCallToAction;
        private LinearLayout adview;


        public NativeAdViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

// Create native UI using the ad metadata.
            nativeAdIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
            nativeAdTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
            nativeAdBody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
            nativeAdMedia = (MediaView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
            nativeAdSocialContext = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
            nativeAdCallToAction = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
            adview=(LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ads_unit);


        }
    }
```

Here is the error

```
01-30 23:13:06.031 14318-14318/comeagain.materialdesign E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: comeagain.materialdesign, PID: 14318
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                          at com.facebook.ads.AdChoicesView.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at com.facebook.ads.AdChoicesView.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at comeagain.materialdesign.adapters.AdapterBoxOffice.onBindViewHolder(AdapterBoxOffice.java:171)
```

Error occurs at this point

```
 AdChoicesView adChoicesView = new AdChoicesView(layoutInflater.getContext(), nativeAd, true);
```

Comment: You are getting NullPointer Error at line 165. Which line is it?

Answer (score 0):

`adView` is null. In your code there was 1 place where you assigned something to adView but that is commented out, and in another place in `onAdLoaded()` you assign it to a local variable.